# On tap/click, hide/show L.control (Leaflet)

Tags: leaflet

I want user to be able to tap screen to toggle L.control, to get a cleaner map.

This is my code to toggle L.control:

```
              var dragged = false
              window.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
                dragged = false
              })
              window.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
                dragged = true
              })           
              $("#mapid").on("click", function () {
                if (dragged == false && $(window).width() < 960) {
                  return $(".leaflet-left").slideToggle(300) && $(".leaflet-right").slideToggle(300);
                }
              })
```

This works, but the problem is that L.control also toggle when the markers on the map is clicked.

How do I ignore this when a marker is clicked?

https://jsfiddle.net/2frpcL4y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Leaflet internal event `click` on the map:

```
map.on("click", function () {
   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      $(".leaflet-left").slideToggle(300) && $(".leaflet-right").slideToggle(300);
   }
})
```

To check if a popup open:

```
function isPopupOpen(){
    var popupOpen = false;
    map.eachLayer((layer)=>{
        if(layer instanceof L.Popup){
            popupOpen = true;
        }
    })
    return popupOpen;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know how to make it ignore a click outside a popup after the popup is opened? Typical what users do to close the popup.